# Generate QR code with a TAB key

Tags: google-sheets, qr-code

How to generate a QR code with a tab key embedded in it using Excel or Google sheets?
Below I have combined data from 5 cells into one cell by using:

```
=CONCATENATE(C16, CHAR(9), C17, CHAR(9), C18, CHAR(9), C19, CHAR(9), C20)
```

How would I generate QR code for this this cell named C25? The cells have text with spaces in them.
This will work for one cell WITHOUT tabs in Google sheets:

```
=if(isblank(C25),"",
  image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl="&
    SUBSTITUTE(C25," ","%20")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `CHAR(9)` to `"%09"` (with quotes) in `CONCATENATE` then replace `qr&chl="&SUBSTITUTE(C25," ","%20")` with `qr&chl=C25)`.